# custom path - selenium not running

Tags: selenium-rc

I'm trying to run tests with a custom firefox profile.my idea is to
use 2 firefox versions in my machine .one with firefox template &
other without it ,so we used
*custom "C:/Program Files (x86)/UtiluMFC/Mozilla Firefox 3.6/
firefox.exe" in setup from code

if i use custom some extra parameters are passing in url like below in
browser ,
selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?
sessionId=dc91ae43b4754f87a25d4718feeb&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A
%2F%2Ftest.com&debugMode=false

Note : i have not started the server from command prompt i have used
in java ,but havnt set any firefox template in code.same worked in
linux of i use * firefox instead of * custom

Am i missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not that clear - what do you mean by template?

If you want to run with two different Firefox profiles, don't use *custom - rather use *firefox and change the profile as per this post:

[Selenium RC : Setting up a Firefox proxy](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/selenium-rc-setting-up-firefox-proxy.html)

Comment: when i used *firefox  it works in command prompt,i want set it from code.i used * custom in linux and it is working?! my requirement is to use custom firefox .

Comment: hi can anyone help my need is to run firefox using * custom instead of * firefox!

Answer (score 0):

I think I am strougling with the same and I believe one has to set the proxy settings in the custom firefox to make it work. Did you try that?

Or did you just want to use a profile TEMPLATE in which case you could pass the `-firefoxProfileTemplate` in your command to start the JAVA server, like so:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "/path/to/profile/"
```

In the second case, if you use `*firefox`, your profile will automatically be selected.

Comment: we are starting the server from code and when we tried to use *custom specifying the firefox path in setup like

*custom "C:/Program Files (x86)/UtiluMFC/Mozilla Firefox 3.6/ firefox.exe" in setup from code

if i use custom some extra parameters are passing in url like below in browser , selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html? sessionId=dc91ae43b4754f87a25d4718feeb&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A %2F%2Ftest.com&debugMode=false